# How to extract number from the below string which is the output of a command?

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, grep, solaris

I want to extract message number which we get on executing command `mailx -H`.
I want the message numbers of unread and new messages only.
I tried with the below command:

```
mailx -H|grep '^ [UN]'|cut -c 3-
```

But it is not giving the required output.It gives the entire line following U or N.
The sample output of mailx -H command is:

```
O 95 abcd Thu Sep  6 20:29   25/1245  Incident: 00291
O 96 efgh Thu Sep  6 20:29   25/1245  Incident: 00291
O 97 abcd  Thu Sep  6 20:29   25/1245 Incident: 00291
O 98 pqrs Thu Sep  6 20:29   25/1245  Incident: 00291
O 99 abcd  Thu Sep  6 20:29   25/1245 Incident: 00291
U100 cnhn Thu Sep  6 20:29   25/1244  Incident: 00291
U101 gont Thu Sep  6 20:29   25/1244  Incident: 00291
U102 qwer Thu Sep  6 20:29   25/1244  Incident: 00291
```

I want number following U or N ie new or unread messages and O(old) messages.
How can this be done in a shell script?
The expected output is

```
95
96
97
98
99
100
101
102
```

Comment: can you share the expected result and distribution of Linux.

Comment: updated it in the question

Comment: Welcome , please add your `grep` version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
mailx -H | nawk -F '[^0-9]+' '/^ [U|N]/ { print $2}'
```

- `[^0-9]+` as an FS.
- extract the lines which started with `U` or `N`
- print second field

Comment: @Devjith are you using solaris?

Comment: @Devjith try with `nawk`

Comment: @Devjith plz mention the distro if your are asking any question in future.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `grep`:

```
grep -P -o '(?<=O|U|N) ?[0-9]+'
```

Example:

```
echo "O 95 abcd Thu Sep  6 20:29   25/1245  Incident: 00291
O 96 efgh Thu Sep  6 20:29   25/1245  Incident: 00291
O 97 abcd  Thu Sep  6 20:29   25/1245 Incident: 00291
O 98 pqrs Thu Sep  6 20:29   25/1245  Incident: 00291
O 99 abcd  Thu Sep  6 20:29   25/1245 Incident: 00291
U100 cnhn Thu Sep  6 20:29   25/1244  Incident: 00291
U101 gont Thu Sep  6 20:29   25/1244  Incident: 00291
U102 qwer Thu Sep  6 20:29   25/1244  Incident: 00291" | grep -P -o '(?<=O|U|N) ?[0-9]+'
 95
 96
 97
 98
 99
100
101
102
```

-

```
grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.27
```

---

If the `grep` above does not work/suffice, try this `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^(O|U|N) ?([0-9]+) .*/\2/g'
```

Example:

```
echo "O 95 abcd Thu Sep  6 20:29   25/1245  Incident: 00291
O 96 efgh Thu Sep  6 20:29   25/1245  Incident: 00291
O 97 abcd  Thu Sep  6 20:29   25/1245 Incident: 00291
O 98 pqrs Thu Sep  6 20:29   25/1245  Incident: 00291
O 99 abcd  Thu Sep  6 20:29   25/1245 Incident: 00291
U100 cnhn Thu Sep  6 20:29   25/1244  Incident: 00291
U101 gont Thu Sep  6 20:29   25/1244  Incident: 00291
U102 qwer Thu Sep  6 20:29   25/1244  Incident: 00291" | sed -E 's/^(O|U|N) ?([0-9]+) .*/\2/g'
95
96
97
98
99
100
101
102
```

Comment: I want the number alone. Also, grep -E -o is shown as an illegal option for me..

Comment: Updated, see above.

Comment: `grep: illegal option -- P
grep: illegal option -- o
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .`  I am getting this error

Comment: What GNU/Linux distribution (if any) are you using?

Comment: I am using this in UNIX....started working on UNIX  few days ago only...so dont know much in detail

Comment: I tried with sed command mentioned above. But getting `sed: illegal option -- E`

Comment: Well... since we don't know your `grep` version, your `sed` version, or which operating system you are using, it is hard to help...